# What Design Patterns do you implement in common Delphi programming?

Tags: delphi, design-patterns

What Design Patterns do you implement in **common Delphi programming**? What patterns are **easier** to adapt in Delphi programming? (Every language is excellent in different fields, so what patterns are likely to be very strong structures when using Delphi?)

I would be glad, if you could tell about some changes in **design patterns for Delphi 2009 / 2010** (since those support generics, and RTTI in 2010).

There are many articles out there in the wild Internet, but they doesn't discuss the everyday usability and changes in patterns. (Most of them just discuss changes in language specifics, architecture).

Comment: Maybe this should be a community wiki question

Comment: Can I ask why? I'm asking a specific question, dealing with design patterns for Delphi and whether they have changed since changes in Delphi's language (2009, 2010)

Comment: Well, no, Juraj, you're not asking a specific question. I count at least *three* questions, and they're all rather open-ended. Not sure whether that's grounds for making something community wiki, though.

Comment: moved to CW, just wanted to know, if there is anyone, who knows about pattern changes in Delphi 2009/2010

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Only a minority of the Delphi developers knows that every Delphi developer uses a [Factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_object) (delphi.about.com has an [example in "regular" Delphi](http://delphi.about.com/od/course/a/delphi_oop26.htm)), but then implemented using virtual Create constructors.

So: time to shed some light on that :-)

Virtual constructors are to classes like virtual methods are like object instances.

The whole idea of the factory pattern is that you decouple the logic that determines what kind (in this case "class") of thing (in this case "object instance") to create from the actual creation.

It works like this using virtual Create constructors:

TComponent has a [virtual Create constructor](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_TComponent_Create.html) so, which can be overridden by any descending class:

```
type
  TComponent = class(TPersistent, ...)
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); virtual;
    ...
  end;
```

For instance the [TDirectoryListBox.Create constructor](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/FileCtrl_TDirectoryListBox_Create.html) overrides it:

```
type
  TDirectoryListBox = class(...)
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    ...
  end;
```

You can store a class reference (the class analogy to an object instance reference) in a variable of type 'class type'. For component classes, there is a predefined type [TComponentClass in the Classes unit](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate4/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_TComponentClass.html):

```
type
  TComponentClass = class of TComponent;
```

When you have a variable (or parameter) of type TComponentClass, you can do polymorphic construction, which is very very similar to the factory pattern:

```
var
  ClassToCreate: TComponentClass;

...

procedure SomeMethodInSomeUnit;
begin
  ClassToCreate := TButton;
end;

...

procedure AnotherMethodInAnotherUnit;
var
  CreatedComponent: TComponent;
begin
  CreatedComponent := ClassToCreate.Create(Application);
  ...
end;
```

The Delphi RTL uses this for instance here:

```
Result := TComponentClass(FindClass(ReadStr)).Create(nil);
```

and here:

```
// create another instance of this kind of grid
SubGrid := TCustomDBGrid(TComponentClass(Self.ClassType).Create(Self));
```

The first use in the Delphi RTL is how the whole creation process works of forms, datamodules, frames and components that are being read from a DFM file.

The form (datamodule/frame/...) classes actually have a (published) list of components that are on the form (datamodule/frame/...). That list includes for each component the instance name and the class reference.
When reading the DFM files, the Delphi RTL then:

1. finds about the components instance name,
2. uses that name to find the underlying class reference,
3. then uses the class reference to dynamically create the correct object

A regular Delphi developer usually never sees that happen, but without it, the whole Delphi RAD experience would not exist.

[Allen Bauer](http://www.linkedin.com/in/abauer) (the Chief Scientist at Embarcadero), wrote a short [blog](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/abauer/) [article about this topic](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/abauer/2003/10/11/258) as well.
There is also a [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/) question about [where virtual constructors are being used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436961/where-virtual-constructors-are-used).

Let me know if that was enough light on the virtual Create constructor topic :-)

--jeroen

Comment: shame I can upvote only once, great post, thank you

Comment: @Tom thanks for the edit; being a bit wordblind, those things are exactly what I always overlook.

Comment: Excellent example. One thing to note. Factory pattern implementations in other languages use ordinary static functions (or _class_ functions for pascalites). As such they are capable of returning null(_nil_). A Delphi constructor, like the nameless constructors in other languages, will always return an object reference unless you raise an exception. You are free, of course, to use a class function just as easily if the need arises.

Answer (score 6):

You can find [an excellent article by Marco Cantu](http://conferences.embarcadero.com/article/33132) on the equivalence of GOF patterns and Delphi idioms. I remember attending his Borcon session on the subject, it was excellent.
One main idea to remember is that design patterns are needed to supplement shortcomings of the language/framework. And if you have a native idiom, you don't need to reinvent the wheel and implement the whole GOF shebang, just learn to recognize it and name it (as Jeroen did with his [superb explanation on the Factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584670/what-design-patterns-do-you-implement-in-common-delphi-programming/1585004#1585004)).

Answer (score 3):

I use frequently following patterns:

- Command
- Visitor
- Table Data Gateway
- Observer
- Adapter
- Singleton (with many care!)
- Abstract Factory
- Factory Method
- State
- Dependency Injection in all of his form
- Facade
- Service Locator
- Separated Interface

Answer (score 2):

I frequently uses the following patterns:

1. Observer in MVC
2. Singlton
3. Template Method
4. State

Comment: There is an answer about Singletons and it says, that they are pure evil. Disguised global variables :)

Comment: Both are only evil if you abuse them. Singletons can be very handy in certain situations.

Answer (score 2):

Non-OOP programming (some call it Structured programming) is very common with Delphi programmers. It is very simple: You create a function that does something, and it is not related to a record/object-like data structure. Example: IntToStr()

Delphi does this very well, because encapsulation is delivered using interface/implementation sections, and because the resulting machine code is extremely efficient. When compiling, it also supports optimizations for that, for instance, if you have a typed constant in your interface section, and the program is fully compiled - if you then change the value of that constant, the unit is not recompiled, only the constant changes. This is not really necessary in a daily work, but it is an example of how Delphi works.

Comment: What does this answer have to do with any of the topics mentioned in the question?

Comment: Non-OOP isn't necessarily "Structured programming". There's Functional Programming too, for example, very interesting topic for Delphi programmers seeking to learn something "alien". Check out http://www.delphifeeds.com/go/s/44177 for a introduction geared at Delphi devs.

Comment: -1 not at all about design patterns

Comment: +1: "non-OOP" is a very important design pattern. It is about KISS. Even though KISS is not mentioned as such in the GOF book, the KISS pattern is one of most important patterns available: it helps you not to 'over-engineer' what you produce. Maybe it is not mentioned in the GoF book because it applies to so much more than just software.

Comment: @Jeroen: KISS is not in the GoF book because it simply isn't a recognizable pattern as such. It is a good idea, yes, but a pattern is something like a handle for a common and proven solution to a class of problems. Patterns are intended to help people solve problems and communicate about it, just throwing out "KISS" does neither.

Comment: @mghie: KISS is much more of a meta pattern than a concrete pattern (the GoF book is more of a 'conrete pattern' reference). I agree with you it is very important to practice.

Comment: It is possible to refactor a procedure with many parameters into a class and vice versa. It's definitely an obvious pattern that can be described and defined well, easily, but I don't care what it is called - I don't have the GoF book nearby, and seriously, it doesn't have a monopoly on naming.

Comment: Lars, just as "non-object-oriented programming" and "keeping it simple" are not patterns, neither is refactoring. And you really *should* care about what something is called — the whole point of patterns is that they give us a **common vocabulary** to use when thinking and talking about problems. Using a name *different* from what the world's most popular pattern book uses doesn't help anyone. You have made several true statements — it *is* possible to refactor a procedure as your describe, and non-OOP *is* very common — but how are they *relevant* to the question at hand?

Answer (score 2):

An ordinary `Unit` behaves like a singleton. You can't use OOP-techniques like inheritance and polymorfism though, but that might be a good thing :)

I generally think that Delphi makes it too easy to avoid sound oop design. That is nice for RAD, but you need to know which pitfalls to avoid if you want a flixible and maintainable code. Eg the public visibility for the components you add to the forms, the global Form1 variable of type TForm1 (instead of manually managed lifetime and a base class as type) and the lack of seperation between GUI and business logic. Just to mention some issues.