# what is the meaning of `Class of ` type declaration?

Tags: class, delphi, c++builder, delphi-xe

While going through one of my code, I am stuck on one statement which is as below.

`TMyObjectClass = class of TMyObject;`

I am a bit confused, and wondering what is the meaning of this statement.
As `TMyObjectClass` has no declaration above the statement.

and `TMyObject` is having declaration as below:

`TMyObject = class(TObject)
  private
     //some private member declaration
  Public
     // some public variables
 end;`

So, my question is what is the meaning of the statement 
 `TMyObjectClass = class of TMyObject;`

and How `TMyObjectClass` works?

I am a bit new to Delphi, so please help me to get some idea about these type of declaration and there workarounds.

Comment: You can read about this topic [`here`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE/en/Class_References).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a [Class Reference](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Class_References).

They are used to work with meta classes. The canonical example is the Delphi streaming framework which uses

```
TComponentClass = class of TComponent;
```

This allows for dynamic binding to virtual constructors. The `TComponent` constructor is `virtual`. The streaming framework needs to instantiate classes derived from `TComponent`. It does so something like this:

```
var
  ComponentClass: TComponentClass;
  Component: TComponent;
....
ComponentClass := GetComponentClassSomehowDoesntMatterHow;
Component := ComponentClass.Create(Owner);
```

Now, because `TComponent.Create` is `virtual`, this is bound in a polymorphic fashion. If `TComponentClass` is `TButton`, then `TButton.Create` is called. If `TComponentClass` is `TPanel`, then `TPanel.Create` is called. And so on.

The most important thing to realise is that the class that is constructed is determined only at runtime. Note that many languages lack this capability, most notably C++.