# How do i know if i need to use a design-pattern?

Tags: delphi, design-patterns, uml

I'm just wondering, I'm new to this pattern subject, I started like couple of weeks ago but my main problem is, when I start writing small applications (for self purposes) I can't think where to put any pattern to use, maybe it's my thinking structure that needs to be tweaked ?

If I start a new project, how would I know if I need to use a pattern ? what questions do I ask myself ? what steps do I take before writing the actual code ?

Comment: I believe this question is too vague and offtopic here. to ask philosophical and conceptual question better go http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ or http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Look at the Delphi VCL...it's basically took the Design Patterns and ran with them...

- Forms are Composite Patterns.
- Datasets use the Iterator Pattern.
- Screen and Application are  Singleton Patterns.
- Components use lots of
  different Patterns,  the Chain of Responsibility, Decorator, Facade
  to name a few...

Patterns are ways to organize your program and objects in lightly coupled objects that have jobs that you do over and over again...

Comment: Virtual constructors are used for the Factory Pattern: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584670/what-design-patterns-do-you-implement-in-common-delphi-programming/1585004#1585004

Answer (score 1):

Design patterns are just ways to approach solutions to common problems. As you internalize the patterns and as you understand the problem better you will sometimes see that the problem (or part of the problem) you are solving is addressed by a particular pattern.

That's when you use it. When you see it solving your problem.

Comment: That's my problem, as I write code, I never know if it has a problem (smelly code), it's like i'm an Anti-Pattern guy.

Comment: Keep writing code. Keep reading about it. When you recognize your code in an anti-pattern book, don't do it again. Sometimes a friend or coworker can review your code. Make sure they know that you want them to tell you everything they see that could improve. Then develop a thick skin and never be defensive.

Answer (score 0):

Design patterns are reusable solutions for common problems.

The principles of Software Engineering cites the reusability of codes, when you use a design pattern you are using a concept previously tested that went trough several validations and is less prone to an design error than if you design your own model.

So first, you have to know the existing design patterns and what they're intended to solution. When you face a common problem you may remember the design patterns you previously studied and use them to solve the situation you're facing at the moment.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. Every time someone downvotes should put a comment on it.