# When do I use a Virtual Constructor in C++

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where virtual constructors are used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436961/where-virtual-constructors-are-used)

Why would we be needing a Virtual Constructor in C++ ?

Though C++ do not directly supporting it. There are several solutions, which enable this feature. I would like to know, when we would be needing such a thing.

Comment: Virtual constructors as in the [Factory Method Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)? Please offer an example of the code you are referring to.

Comment: Yes. or like in prototype pattern. Want to know the scenario of usage.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=C%2B%2B+virtual+Constructor ? also, what are you trying to achieve? virtual constructor is a quite loose term.

Comment: @vamsi They would be used when a Factory Pattern is desired. You should look at it from the patterns point of view.

Answer (score 6):

A virtual constructor is the ability to clone an object, without actually knowing what type it is.  This is very useful when we do not know the *real* type of an object, but need a copy of it.  Let's say we have a base-class thusly:

```
class Object
{
public:
    Object() {};
    virtual ~Object(){} = 0;
    virtual Object* clone() const = 0;
};
```

And we derive a bunch of stuff from it:

```
class MyClass : public Object
{
public:
    MyClass() {};
    MyClass(const MyClass& rhs) {}; // copy-constructor
    virtual ~MyClass() { };
    virtual MyClass* clone() const { return new MyClass(*this); }; // virtual ctor
};

class AnotherClass : public Object { /* etc */ };
```

Now, suppose we have a vector of these Object-derived classes:

```
std::vector<Object*> objects;
objects.push_back(new MyClass());
objects.push_back(new AnotherClass());
```

Ok, now I'd like to make a copy of all the objects in that vector and put them in another one.  Here is where our clone comes in!

```
std::vector<Object*> anotherVector;
for(std::vector<Object*>::const_iterator cit(objects.begin());
    cit != objects.end();
    ++cit)
    anotherVector.push_back((*cit)->clone());
```

So without having to know what actual type the Object-derived classes are, we can make a copy of them through the `clone()` function which basically just calls it's own copy-constructor.

NOTE: This is just one possible use for using a virtual constructor.  There are plenty of other times you might want to copy something and not know its actual class.

Comment: +1 though to be precise this is a virtual *copy* constructor and as such has a very specific use.

Comment: I understand the usage in such scenario. However, As per my understanding, virtual means, something to be determined late (like at run-time), So virtual constructor means, constructing an object at run-time based on some input parameters. Example:  In factory method, we create a derived class based on some parameter at run-time. Is it also another application of virtual constructor ?